# Setup kafka and zooker with Docker for development

Tags: docker, apache-kafka, docker-compose, apache-zookeeper

I'm trying to setup Kafka and zookeeper for development and I'm following [this tutorial](https://github.com/bitnami/bitnami-docker-kafka#kafka-development-setup-example):

```
version: "3"
services:
  zookeeper:
    image: 'bitnami/zookeeper:latest'
    ports:
      - '2181:2181'
    environment:
      - ALLOW_ANONYMOUS_LOGIN=yes
  kafka-src:
    image: 'bitnami/kafka:latest'
    ports:
      - '9092:9092'
    environment:
      - KAFKA_BROKER_ID=1
      - KAFKA_LISTENERS=PLAINTEXT://:9092
      - KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS=PLAINTEXT://127.0.0.1:9092
      - KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT=zookeeper:2181
      - ALLOW_PLAINTEXT_LISTENER=yes
    depends_on:
      - zookeeper
  kafka-dst:
    image: 'bitnami/kafka:latest'
    ports:
      - '9093:9093'
    environment:
      - KAFKA_BROKER_ID=2
      - KAFKA_LISTENERS=PLAINTEXT://:9093
      - KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS=PLAINTEXT://127.0.0.1:9093
      - KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT=zookeeper:2181
      - ALLOW_PLAINTEXT_LISTENER=yes
    depends_on:
      - zookeeper
```

But when I do `docker-compose up` I'm getting the error `Connection to node 2 (/127.0.0.1:9093) could not be established. Broker may not be available. (org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient)`

My overall goal is to be able to setup kafka for development environment.

Thanks

Comment: Unclear what is returning that error. Does having only one broker work okay?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems that section of the README wasn't updated when the variables were renamed (I don't know why they did that)

The variables now start with `KAFKA_CFG`, as shown in other sections of the page, which would possibly explain why the listener properties you have overridden from the defaults do not work.

[This section](https://github.com/bitnami/bitnami-docker-kafka#accessing-kafka-with-internal-and-external-clients) that I wrote *is correct*

Note, there's already a cluster file in the repo - https://github.com/bitnami/bitnami-docker-kafka/blob/master/docker-compose-cluster.yml

However, a single machine is a single point of failure, so having two brokers in one compose file isn't going to help with resiliency or throughput. Especially since you've not configured internal topics to have a default replication factor of more than one

Answer (score 0):

i think zookeeper cannot find kafka and kafka cannot find zookeeper
becouse localHost name conflict
if use Ubuntu OS used this way? if Ubuntu i think you need change setup hosts from /etc/hosts

look this link http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man5/hosts.5.html

and this is soultion

```
[your ip Address] [local Host]
140...1           localhost
140...1           abed-Inspiron-5593
140...1           release.gitkraken.com
140...1           mysql
140...1           eurekaserver
140...1           keycloak
140...1           kafka
140...1           zookeeper
```

Comment: Please do not suggest to edit the hosts file to fix this issue. The proper way is to understand how Kafka advertises itself on the network

Comment: you must be update host file because zookeeper cant show localhost for kafka

Comment: in this case i have many localhost and have same name localhost how zookeeper selected right localhost if dont update localhost name

Comment: nah man. that does not make sense. If i remove one of the two kafka instances, everything gets resolved without touching the hosts file

Comment: Sounds like you don't understand `advertised.listeners` properly @Abdalrhman